# How can my own implementation of Find References write to the Eclipse Search View?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I am using the Eclipse plugin framework to write an editor for a specific language. I would like to implement a Find Reference capability for this language and write the results to the eclipse Search View. I've been searching the web for a few days now, and all I found was explanations on how the define the org.eclipse.search.searchResultViewPages extension point and define a search page and a search view. I am only interested in the Search View and how I can plug in my own results to it.
Thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid you have found the complete answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have started to work on the same problem.

For me, the easiest thing to do was to add a command handler for the existing Java find references command *org.eclipse.jdt.ui.edit.text.java.search.references.in.workspace* when in the context of my editor.

The current version of my handler is very simple, and it sends a regular expression based on the current word to a simple text search (admittedly, producing false positives). On the plus side, the results get plugged into the search results as you would like, and I didn't have to deal with search views.

The important thing seems to be that your handler end with a call like this:

```
NewSearchUI.runQueryInBackground(query);
```

In order to prepare my simple text query, I use

```
ISearchQuery query = TextSearchQueryProvider.getPreferred().createQuery(new PigSearchInput(word));
```

You can look at my complete handler class [here.](https://github.com/eyala/pig-eclipse/blob/master/org.apache.pig.contrib.eclipse/src/org/apache/pig/contrib/eclipse/FindReferencesHandler.java) It's mostly self contained. In the future I plan on implementing a "real" find references feature,, using my own classes instead of the Eclipse text search ones, but I haven't done this yet.